# Bounding box in AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to get bounding box from an image in Rekognition, i get the label but i get:

> Keyerror'instances' in response['instances']

```
def detect_labels(bucket, key, max_labels=10, min_confidence=90, region="eu-west-1"):
    rekognition = session.client("rekognition", region)
    response = rekognition.detect_labels(
        Image={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Name": key,
            }
        }, MaxLabels=10
    )
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":

response= detect_labels(BUCKET, KEY)

    print('Detected labels for ' + photo) 
    print()   
    for label in response['Labels']:

        for instance in label['Instances']:
            print ("  Bounding box")
            print ("    Top: " + str(instance['BoundingBox']['Top']))

        print ("----------")
        print ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure that you are using an up to date boto3 SDK. I have found that boto3 v1.9.20 does not return the instances array, while the current v1.9.84 does return it.

That aside, the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.detect_labels) states:

> If Label represents an object, Instances contains the bounding boxes
>   for each instance ...

That seems to imply that instances will only be present if the label represents an object. Your code should check that a given label actually has instances, for example:

```
if 'Instances' in label:
    for instance in label['Instances']:
        # print details of instance
```

It would also be simple to confirm this by simply printing the `label` dict as a JSON string and seeing what it actually contains.

Comment: It doesn't work. My version is '1.9.85', and the system finds labels